# RabbitMQ managment Nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, rabbitmq

I have loadbalancer and vm with rabbitmq broker. On rabbitmq open 5672 port with plugin managment if I am create proxy to rabbitmq recive

> > curl: (52) Empty reply from server

I am can connect with telnet to rmq server and have callback

> > curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Nginx config

```
server {
    listen    xxx.xxx.xxx.yy:80;
    server_name xxxxxxxxxx
    access_log acces.log;
    error_log error.log;
    location / {
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
            proxy_send_timeout   90;
            proxy_read_timeout   90;
            proxy_buffer_size    4k;
            proxy_buffers     16 32k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
            proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
            proxy_pass   http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:5672;
            proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh, I am mistaken the port for management plugin, it's 15672, not 5672. All good

```
server {
    listen    xxx.xxx.xxx.yy:80;
    server_name xxxxxxxxxx
    access_log acces.log;
    error_log error.log;
    location / {
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_send_timeout   90;
        proxy_read_timeout   90;
        proxy_buffer_size    4k;
        proxy_buffers     16 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
        proxy_pass   http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:15672;
        proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```